# How to use Windows environment variables in Vim script?

Tags: windows, vim, environment

I have a Vim script that calls an external shell script and reads the output into the current buffer. It works fine in Unix systems. I'm trying to make the script OS-agnostic, so I want it to work for Windows users too. Here's the relevant line from the script:

```
:exe ":0r !$HOME/bin/shell_script"
```

According to Vim's docs, `$HOME` should translate fine for Windows users too.  Using gvim on Win XP in command mode, doing

```
:echo $HOME
```

does indeed produce "C:\Documents and Settings\my_user".

However, my Vim script (adjusted for backslashes) fails on the Windows machine with a message in the DOS cmd.exe window saying

> $HOME\bin\shell_script" not found.

In other words, Vim appears not to be expanding the value of `$HOME` before passing it to cmd.exe.

I can't use `%APPDATA%` either because Vim interprets `%` as the current file and pre/appends the file name to `APPDATA`.  Weird that Vim *does* expand `%` but doesn't expand `$HOME`.

How do I get `$HOME` expanded correctly?  Is it because I'm using `exe` in the vim script?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `!` to read a file.

```
:exe ":0r $HOME/bin/shell_script"
```

Or read `type` command in windows(like `cat` in linux):

```
:exe '0r !type "'. $HOME . '\bin\shell_script"'
```

**Note:**

- the `type` is executed in windows shell, so you need `\`(backslash) in path
- if `$HOME` contains `space`s, you need `"`(double-quote) to preserves the literal value of `space`s

Comment: To clarify, I want to execute the external script and insert the output into the buffer.

Comment: I missed that you had moved $HOME outside the quotes.  That fixed it.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the answer given by kev:

On windows the $HOME variable do not expand properly when you escape to the console. For example, consider this code:

```
:e $HOME/myscript
```

This works because vim expands $HOME as normal. On the other hand this won't work:

```
:%! $HOME/myscript
```

Why? Because vim passes everything after `!` to the underlying shell, which on Windows is `cmd.exe` which does environment variables `%LIKE_THIS%`. If you try to use that notation, vim will jump in and expand `%` to the name of the current file - go figure.

How to get around it? Use `exe` keyword:

```
:exe "%! ".$HOME."\myscript"
```

Let's analyze:

- `:exe` is a command that takes a string and evaluates it (think eval in most languages)
- `"!% "` the escape to shell command. Note that it is quoted so that exe can evaluate it. Also note how there is an extra space there so that when we append the home var it does not but right against it
- `.$HOME` the dot is a string concatenation symbol. The `$HOME` is outside of the quotes but concatenated so that vim can expand it properly
- `."/myscript"` path to script and possible arguments (also quoted)

  The important thing here is keeping `$HOME` outside of the quote marks, otherwise it may not be properly expanded on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like the `expand` function. For example:

```
:echo expand("$HOME/hello")
/home/amir/hello
```

You can find out more info about expand() with `:help expand`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some information about slashes and backslashes in vim:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/os_dos.html

> When you prefer to use forward slashes, set the 'shellslash' option. 
>   Vim will then replace backslashes with forward slashes when expanding
>   file names.  This is especially useful when using a Unix-like 'shell'.

Comment: This question is not about (back)slashes. The problem here is the shell simply doesn't understand `$HOME`